# Is there direct notation for this sum

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, summation, self-learning

for this boy here I don't know how to deal with the dependence to the outer sum or the floor $$f(x)=2+\sum_{i=0}^{x-1}\left(4+1+\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\frac{x-1}{2}\rfloor}(2+1)+1\right)+3$$

Comment: try decomposing between odd and even $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{k=a}^b c=(b-a+1)c$ (perhaps only under the premise that  $b\ge a-1$). Thus
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor \frac{x-1}2\rfloor}(2+1)=3\cdot\left\lfloor \frac{x-1}2\right\rfloor$$
and
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=5+x\cdot\left(6+3\cdot\left\lfloor \frac{x-1}2\right\rfloor\right) \\&=5+6x+3x\left\lfloor \frac{x-1}2\right\rfloor\\
&=\begin{cases}\frac32x^2+\frac92x+5&\text{if $x$ is odd}\\
\frac32x^2+3x+5&\text{if $x$ is even.}\end{cases}\end{align}$$